# Слитное/раздельное написание "не"

Tags: частица-не, частица

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему "Она была невиновна" пишется слитно (как я понимаю, по аналогии с полной формой прилагательного), а "Она была не виновата" — раздельно?
Благодарю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Невиновна* пишется слитно по общему правилу: частица *не* пишется слитно с прилагательным, если в сочетании с ним образуется слово противоположного значения и не подразумевается противопоставления. Это правило распространяется и на полные, и на краткие прилагательные (как в вашем случае). Думаю, тут и так всё понятно.

А почему *не виновата* пишется раздельно? Для того чтобы это понять, проанализируйте два списка прилагательных, в которых присутствует полная и краткая форма каждого слова.

A)

1. Красивый — красив
2. Краткий — краток
3. Виновный — виновен

Б)

1. Согласный — согласен
2. Виноватый — виноват
3. Способный — способен

Посмотрите на эти два списка повнимательнее. Чем они отличаются? А тем, что в первом списке у прилагательных при переходе из полной формы в краткую смысл никак не менялся, а во **втором значение прилагательных изменялось** (мы смотрим на эти слова **без учёта контекста**, не рассматриваем их употребление с зависимыми словами, то есть анализируем значение слов в голом виде):

Согласный — дружный (согласные движения)
Согласен — придерживающийся одинакового мнения (согласен с тобой)

Виноватый — выражающий сознание вины (виноватые глаза)
Виноват — провинившийся (я во всем виноват)

Способный — одаренный (способные дети) 
Способен — умеющий делать что-либо (способен быть серьезным)

**По правилу Розенталя краткие прилагательные, имеющие в полной форме иное значение, пишутся с *"не"* раздельно.**

Слово *виновата*, как мы выше выяснили, подходит под это правило, поэтому с отрицательной частицей *не* пишется раздельно:

***Она была не виновата.***

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ!